# Extracting Geolocation from React state objects

Tags: api, object, reactjs, geolocation, double

I'm doing something using Geolocation API and ReactJS, and I'm storing location as a state variable, since the component changes location as the web page moves around or as the user randomly changes location.

So the component looks like this:

```
var GeoComp = React.createClass({
    setPosition: function(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    this.setState({longitude: {longitude}, latitude: {lat}});
    this.setState({statusText: 'Successfully found you at ' + this.state.longitude + ',' + this.state.latitude});
},
getInitialState: function(){
    return {longitude: 0, latitude: 0, placeName: '', statusText: 'Locating you....'};

},
componentDidMount: function(){
    if (!navigator.geolocation){
        this.setState({statusText: 'Your browser does not support geolocation...'});
    }
    else{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition, this.errorPosition);
    }
}
```

......

But the problem I'm running into is extracting the double from longitude and latitude variables. React stores them as objects. How can I actually store the doubles and pass them to child components?

Comment: Just to be more specific, when I do something like console.log(this.state.latitude) I get [object Object] but not a double, which is what I'm trying to do. It's key/value or key/id and I'm unable to get the actual double.

Comment: Never mind, I was doing something braindead in setting initial state. This is much more straightforward than I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry -- the problem was poor syntax when setting up initialState:

```
this.setState({longitude: longitude, latitude: lat});
```

as opposed to

```
this.setState({longitude: {longitude}, latitude: {lat}});
```

It's a n00b mistake about how React syntax works :-/